# Use the same file link for both Linux and Windows

Tags: windows, hard-link

Is it even possible to do so? I mean, can I create a link on Linux and than make this link valid also on Windows?

#### Use-case

I have the folder `/media/Data/DownloadedMusic` on a NTFS partition. I also have the folder `/media/Data/Music` on the same partition.  How can I create a link to DownloadedMusic inside Music so that the link can be accessible both from a Linux system and a Windows system?

Comment: This is dependent on the filesystem, but yes this can be done with hardlinks if you use ntfs as filesystem.

Comment: added further infos in the OQ

Answer (score 1):

Windows can't read the Linux filesystem.  However Linux can read the Windows filesystem.  So if you have your /media/Data/Music on a Windows file system you can have access to that space (the same files) on both Windows and Linux.  However, if it's on a Linux filesystem you can only have access to it from Linux.

Making a Windows Filesystem (NTFS) would be the absolute answer.  However, you loose functionality with the windows FS over the linux FS.

You could solve this by making a Linux fileserver and placing your music data on the server.  Then you can have a the same link from Linux (via samba) and Windows (via it's native networking).

A linux fileserver doesn't require a lot of PC power.  You can take an old PC that is ready for the dump, put the minimum linux configuration and a hard drive in it and have a very convenient drive access.

Answer (score 0):

There isn't a single command/method that I've seen that will give you this easily, but rather you'll have to create this linkage yourself using a variety of components.

For starters, on Linux you can have the system automount the NTFS partition via the `/etc/fstab` file anytime that it boots.

```
/dev/sda2   /mnt/somedir ntfs-3g    permissions,locale=en_US.utf8    1   2
```

Then within the NTFS partition, while it's booted to Windows, you could create a [junction point or symbolic link](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/junction-points-and-symbolic-links/) inside the directory `C:\Data\Music` to `C:\Data\DownloadedMusic`.

I have not tried this before but it looks like you can also do this from the Linux side using the `setattr` command to create a junction point.

```
# Display the reparse data of the file source-file
$ getfattr -h -e hex -n system.ntfs_reparse_data source-file

# Copy the reparse data of the file source-file
# to the file target-file
$ REPARSE=`getfattr -h -e hex -n system.ntfs_reparse_data source-file | \
         grep '=' | sed -e 's/^.*=//'`
$ setfattr -h -v $REPARSE -n system.ntfs_reparse_data target-file
```

#### References

- [Junction Points and Symbolic Links](http://www.tuxera.com/community/ntfs-3g-advanced/junction-points-and-symbolic-links/)
- [Create NTFS symbolic links from within Linux](https://serverfault.com/questions/165389/create-ntfs-symbolic-links-from-within-linux)